# Background Process, no user interaction - android

Tags: java, android

I have an app in Android where the user can refresh his data manually (Example: Consumed sms, Total Balance ... ).

However I need a new feature:
 - Implement a schedulle or alarm, where the data of the user will be refreshed every morning without user interaction (Background Process)

I tried with Services class... But I have not clear yet

Thanks

Comment: I need a similar functionality for my app, and am a newbie for Android. Care to share few words if you manage to solve the problem on your own?